# How to design html page before converting to pdf?

Tags: javascript, laravel, dompdf

I was using `"thujohn/pdf": "dev-master"` with Laravel 4.2. I migrated my site to Laravel 5.7 so I had to abandon that package and installed `"barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "^0.8.4"`.I had this blade view that was converted to pdf. The code of the view is the same but when I download the pdf file the design of the page is not the same and everything is messed up. I want to change the CSS of the view that is converted to pdf like a normal web page is there a way to do this?

```
$pdf =  PDF::loadView('pdf.statistique',$data);
return $pdf->download('statistique.pdf');
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr-FR">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="author" content="Association Amis des oiseaux">
 <style type="text/css">
  body{
   position: relative;
   background: #fff;
   height: 100%;
   border: 1px solid #0063a8;
  }

  .header{
   height: 70px;
   margin-bottom: 7px;
   border-bottom: 1px solid #0063a8;
  }
 
  .header .logo{
   width: 285px;
   display: inline-block;
  }
  .header .logo img{
   height: 65px;
  }

  .header .rapport{
   position: absolute;
   top: -8px;
   left: 480px;
   width: 300px;
  }
  .header .rapport h2{
   color: #0163A8;
   font-size: 24px;
  }
  .header .rapport h2 span{
   font-size: 16px;
  }

  .panel-body{
   color: #777;
  }
  .panel-body .panel-content{
   padding: 10px;
  }
  .panel-body .panel-content h3{
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
  }
  .panel-body .panel-content h3.content-title {
      font-size: 14px;
      padding: 7px 10px;
      margin-bottom: 13px;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #777;
      background: #dee6ec;
  }
  .panel-body .panel-content h3.content-title span{
   font-size: 12px;
  }
  .type-infraction .categ_stat_img{
   width: 24.5%;
   display: inline-block;
   position: relative;
   text-align: center;
  }
  .type-infraction .categ_stat_img img{
   width: 100px;
   margin-top: 0;
  }
  .type-infraction .categ_stat_img h4{
      font-size: 14px;
      text-align: center;
      margin: 8px 0;
  }

  p.panel-content-result{
   text-align: center;
   margin: 20px;
  }

  table {
      width: 100%;
  }
  table thead{
   border-bottom: 2px solid #ddd;
  }
  table tbody{
   text-align: center;
  }
  table tbody tr th{
   font-size: 15px;
   padding: 0;
  }
  table tbody tr td{
   border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
   padding: 3px 0;
   font-size: 14px;
  }
  
  .governorate{
      position: relative !important;
      width: 100%;
      height: 150px;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #777;
      border-left: 1px solid #777;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
     .governorate ul{
      position: relative !important;
        margin: 0;
        height: 100%;
     }
     .governorate ul li{
        margin: 0 5px;
        list-style: none;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 20px;
        background: #1faaea;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 716px;
        text-align: center;
     }
     .governorate ul li span{
      color: #fff;
      font-size: 10px;
     }
     .governorate ul li p{
      color: #777;
   position: absolute;
      bottom: 615px;
      transform: rotate(-60deg);
      margin: 0;
      width: 100px;
      left: -50px;
      font-size: 12px;
      text-align: right;
     }
     .governorate ul li:nth-child(1){
        left: 10px;
     }
     .governorate ul li:nth-child(2){
        left: 38px;
     }
     .governorate ul li:nth-child(3){
        left: 66px;
     }
     .governorate ul li:nth-child(4){
        left: 94px;
     }
     .governorate ul li:nth-child(5){
        left: 122px;
     }
     .governorate ul li:nth-child(6){
        left: 150px;
     }
     .governorate ul li:nth-child(7){
        left: 178px;
     }
     .governorate ul li:nth-child(8){
        left: 206px;
     }
     .governorate ul li:nth-child(9){
        left: 234px;
     }
     .governorate ul li:nth-child(10){
        left: 262px;
     }
     .governorate ul li:nth-child(11){
        left: 290px;
     }
     .governorate ul li:nth-child(12){
        left: 318px;
     }
     .governorate ul li:nth-child(13){
        left: 346px;
     }
     .governorate ul li:nth-child(14){
        left: 374px;
     }
     .governorate ul li:nth-child(15){
        left: 402px;
     }
     .governorate ul li:nth-child(16){
        left: 430px;
     }
     .governorate ul li:nth-child(17){
        left: 458px;
     }
     .governorate ul li:nth-child(18){
        left: 486px;
     }
     .governorate ul li:nth-child(19){
        left: 514px;
     }
     .governorate ul li:nth-child(20){
        left: 542px;
     }
     .governorate ul li:nth-child(21){
        left: 570px;
     }
     .governorate ul li:nth-child(22){
        left: 598px;
     }
     .governorate ul li:nth-child(23){
        left: 626px;
     }
     .governorate ul li:nth-child(24){
        left: 654px;
     }

     .groupe-espece{
      position: relative !important;
      width: 100%;
      height: 150px;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #777;
      border-left: 1px solid #777;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
     }
     .groupe-espece ul{
      position: relative !important;
        margin: 0;
        height: 100%;
     }
     .groupe-espece ul li{
        margin: 0 5px;
        list-style: none;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 60px;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 463px;
        text-align: center;
     }
     .groupe-espece ul li span{
      color: #fff;
      font-size: 14px;
     }
     .groupe-espece ul li:nth-child(1){
        left: 30px;
        background: #434448;
     }
     .groupe-espece ul li:nth-child(2){
        left: 130px;
        background: #81b4e1;
     }
     .groupe-espece ul li:nth-child(3){
        left: 230px;
        background: #9cce79;
     }
     .groupe-espece ul li:nth-child(4){
        left: 330px;
        background: #f8a45b;
     }

     .groupe-espece-liste{
      position: absolute;
      left: 450px;
      bottom: 468px;
     }

     .groupe-espece-liste ul li{
        margin: 8px 0;
        list-style: none;
     }
  
  .groupe-espece-liste ul li span{
      width: 10px;
      height: 10px;
      line-height: 10px;
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
      margin-right: 10px;
      margin-top: 5px;
     }
     .groupe-espece-liste ul li:nth-child(1) span{
      background: #434448;
     }
     .groupe-espece-liste ul li:nth-child(2) span{
      background: #81b4e1;
     }
     .groupe-espece-liste ul li:nth-child(3) span{
      background: #9cce79;
     }
     .groupe-espece-liste ul li:nth-child(4) span{
      background: #f8a45b;
     }
  
  .footer{
   color: #777;
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;
   padding: 10px;
   margin: 0 5px 3px 5px;
   background: #DEE6EC;
   width: 100%;
   height: 60px;
  }
  .footer .footer-left{
   width: 50%;
   display: inline-block;
  }
  .footer p{
   margin: 0;
   font-size: 12px;
   font-weight: 300;
  }
  .footer .footer-right{
   width: 50%;
   display: inline-block;
  }
  .footer .footer-right p{
   text-align: right;
   padding-right: 2px;
   margin-top: 15px;
  }
  /*.bg-dark {
      border-bottom: 1px solid #0063a8;
      color: #fff;
      overflow: hidden; position: 
      relative; width: 100%; 
      background-image: url('../images/header/list-reserves.jpg'); 
      background-attachment: fixed; 
      background-size: cover; 
      -moz-background-size: cover; 
      -webkit-background-size: cover; 
      background-repeat: no-repeat; 
      background-position: top center;
  }
  .bg-dark:after{
      content: '';
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
      height: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      top: 0;
  }

  .bg-dark .wpb_wrapper{
      z-index: 9;
      position: relative;
  }

  .spacing {
      margin: 30px 0;
  }

  .white-title h2 {
      font-size: 25px;
      color: #fff;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
      font-weight: 400;
  }

  .black-title h2 {
      font-size: 25px;
      color: #222222;
      margin-bottom: 30px;
      font-weight: 300;
  }*/
 </style>
 <title>Rapport statistique</title>
</head>
<body>

 <div class="panel-body">
     <div class="panel-content">
   <div class="header">
    <div class="logo">
     <img src="assets/images/logo/three-logos.png">
    </div>
    <div class="rapport">

     <h2>
      Rapport statistique<br>
      @if($date_from != '')
      <span>(Du {{ date("d/m/Y", strtotime($date_from)) }}</span>
      @else
      <span>(Du {{ date("d/m/Y", strtotime(App\Http\Controllers\ClaimController::getFirstClaim()->created_at)) }}</span>
      @endif
      @if($date_to != '')
                        <span>au {{ date("d/m/Y", strtotime($date_to)) }})</span>
                        @else
                        <span>au {{ date("d/m/Y") }})</span>
                        @endif
     </h2>
    </div>
   </div>
   {{-- <section class="section bg-dark">
              <div class="">
                  <div class="wpb_wrapper">
                      <div class="white-title text-center">
                          <h2>Le statut des réclamations en temps réel</h2>
                      </div>
                      <div class="row align-vertical">
                          
                          <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 spacing text-center">
                              <div class="service-container wow fadeInLeft" data-wow-delay="0ms" data-wow-duration="1500ms">
                                  <div class="stat parallaxe bg-1">
                                      <span>{{ App\Http\Controllers\ClaimController::getCountEtatClaim('Résolue') }}</span>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="service-body">
                                      <div class="service-title">
                                          <h2>Réclamations résolues</h2>
                                      </div>
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                         
                          <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 spacing text-center">
                              <div class="service-container wow fadeInDown" data-wow-delay="0ms" data-wow-duration="1500ms">
                                  <div class="stat parallaxe bg-2">
                                      <span>{{ App\Http\Controllers\ClaimController::getCountEtatClaim('Non résolue') }}</span>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="service-body">
                                      <div class="service-title">
                                          <h2>Réclamations non résolues</h2>
                                      </div>
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                          
                          <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 spacing text-center">
                              <div class="service-container wow fadeInRight" data-wow-delay="0ms" data-wow-duration="1500ms">
                                  <div class="stat parallaxe bg-3">
                                      <span>{{ App\Http\Controllers\ClaimController::getCountEtatClaim('En cours de traitement') }}</span>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="service-body">
                                      <div class="service-title">
                                          <h2>Réclamations en cours</h2>
                                      </div>
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                          </div>
              
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
            </section> --}}
            <p>{{App\Http\Controllers\CompanyController::getcompany()->introduction}}</p>
      <h3 class="content-title">
                Nombre d'infractions par gouvernorat
                @if($group_oiseau != 'all' || $type_infraction != 'all')
               <span>(</span>
               @endif
               @if($group_oiseau != 'all')
               <span>Groupe: {{ $group_oiseau }}</span>
               @endif
               @if($group_oiseau != 'all' && $type_infraction != 'all')
               <span> / </span>
               @endif
               @if($type_infraction == 'cas01')
               <span>Catégorie: Braconnage</span>
               @elseif($type_infraction == 'cas02')
               <span>Catégorie: Commerce illégal</span>
               @elseif($type_infraction == 'cas03')
               <span>Catégorie: Détention illégale</span>
               @elseif($type_infraction == 'cas04')
               <span>Catégorie: Autres cas de mortalité</span>
               @endif
               @if($group_oiseau != 'all' || $type_infraction != 'all')
               <span>)</span>
               @endif
            </h3>
            
            @if($max_gov > 0)
   <div class="governorate">
    <ul>
     
     @foreach($govs as $gov)
     <li style="height: {{ ((App\Http\Controllers\StatistiqueController::getClaimFromCountry($gov->id,$date_from,$date_to,$group_oiseau,$type_infraction,$espece)*100)/$max_gov)*1.5 }}px;">
      <span>{{ App\Http\Controllers\StatistiqueController::getClaimFromCountry($gov->id,$date_from,$date_to,$group_oiseau,$type_infraction,$espece) }}</span>
      <p>{{ $gov->title_fr }}</p>
     </li>
     @endforeach()
    </ul>
   </div>
   <div style="height: 48px;"></div>
   @else
            <p class="panel-content-result">Pas de résultat pour cette section</p>
            @endif

            <h3 class="content-title">
                Nombre d'infractions par groupe d'espèces
                @if($governorat_id != 'all' || $type_infraction != 'all')
               <span>(</span>
               @endif
               @if($governorat_id != 'all')
               <span>Gouvernorat: {{ App\Http\Controllers\StatistiqueController::getGovId($governorat_id)->title_fr }}</span>
               @endif
               @if($governorat_id != 'all' && $type_infraction != 'all')
               <span> / </span>
               @endif
               @if($type_infraction == 'cas01')
               <span>Catégorie: Braconnage</span>
               @elseif($type_infraction == 'cas02')
               <span>Catégorie: Commerce illégal</span>
               @elseif($type_infraction == 'cas03')
               <span>Catégorie: Détention illégale</span>
               @elseif($type_infraction == 'cas04')
               <span>Catégorie: Autres cas de mortalité</span>
               @endif
               @if($governorat_id != 'all' || $type_infraction != 'all')
               <span>)</span>
               @endif
            </h3>
 
   @if($max_group > 0)
            <div class="groupe-espece">
             <ul>
              <li style="height: {{ (($rapace*100)/$max_group)*1.5 }}px;"><span>{{ round($rapace*100/$all_cas,1) }} %</span></li>
              <li style="height: {{ (($passereaux*100)/$max_group)*1.5 }}px;"><span>{{ round($passereaux*100/$all_cas,1) }} %</span></li>
              <li style="height: {{ (($oiseaux_eau*100)/$max_group)*1.5 }}px;"><span>{{ round($oiseaux_eau*100/$all_cas,1) }} %</span></li>
              <li style="height: {{ (($group_other*100)/$max_group)*1.5 }}px;"><span>{{ round($group_other*100/$all_cas,1) }} %</span></li>
             </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="groupe-espece-liste">
             <ul>
              <li><span></span>Rapaces</li>
              <li><span></span>Passereaux</li>
              <li><span></span>Oiseau d'eau</li>
              <li><span></span>Autres</li>
             </ul>
            </div>
            @else
            <p class="panel-content-result">Pas de résultat pour cette section</p>
            @endif

            <h3 class="content-title">
                Nombre d'infractions par catégorie
                @if($governorat_id != 'all' || $group_oiseau != 'all')
               <span>(</span>
               @endif
               @if($governorat_id != 'all')
               <span>Gouvernorat: {{ App\Http\Controllers\StatistiqueController::getGovId($governorat_id)->title_fr }}</span>
               @endif
               @if($governorat_id != 'all' && $group_oiseau != 'all')
               <span> / </span>
               @endif
               @if($group_oiseau != 'all')
              <span>Groupe: {{ $group_oiseau }}</span>
               @endif
               @if($governorat_id != 'all' || $group_oiseau != 'all')
               <span>)</span>
               @endif
            </h3>

            <div class="type-infraction">
             <div class="categ_stat_img">
              <img src="assets/images/icone/stat01.png">
              <h4>Braconnage: {{ $cas01 }}</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="categ_stat_img">
              <img src="assets/images/icone/stat02.png">
              <h4>Commerce illégal: {{ $cas02 }}</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="categ_stat_img">
              <img src="assets/images/icone/stat03.png">
              <h4>Détention illégale: {{ $cas03 }}</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="categ_stat_img">
              <img src="assets/images/icone/stat04.png">
              <h4>Autres cas de mortalité: {{ $cas04 }}</h4>
                </div>
            </div>

            <h3 class="content-title">
                Les espèces d'oiseaux les plus visées & Nombre d'infractions
                @if($governorat_id != 'all' || $group_oiseau != 'all' || $type_infraction != 'all')
               <span>(</span>
               @endif
               @if($governorat_id != 'all')
               <span>Gouvernorat: {{ App\Http\Controllers\StatistiqueController::getGovId($governorat_id)->title_fr }}</span>
               @endif
               @if(($governorat_id != 'all' && $group_oiseau != 'all') || ($governorat_id != 'all' && $type_infraction != 'all'))
               <span> / </span>
               @endif
               @if($group_oiseau != 'all')
               <span>Groupe: {{ $group_oiseau }}</span>
               @endif
               @if($group_oiseau != 'all' && $type_infraction != 'all')
               <span> / </span>
               @endif
               @if($type_infraction == 'cas01')
               <span>Catégorie: Braconnage</span>
               @elseif($type_infraction == 'cas02')
               <span>Catégorie: Commerce illégal</span>
               @elseif($type_infraction == 'cas03')
               <span>Catégorie: Détention illégale</span>
               @elseif($type_infraction == 'cas04')
               <span>Catégorie: Autres cas de mortalité</span>
               @endif
               @if($governorat_id != 'all' || $group_oiseau != 'all' || $type_infraction != 'all')
               <span>)</span>
               @endif
            </h3>

   @if($birds != '[]')
            <table class="">
               <thead> 
                 <tr> 
                    <th>Nom de l'espèce</th> 
                    <th class="text-center">Nombre d'infraction</th>
                 </tr> 
               </thead>
               <tbody>
                @foreach($birds as $bird)
                 <tr>
                    <td>{{ $bird->bird->title_fr }}</td> 
                    <td class="text-center">{{ $bird->count }}</td> 
                 </tr>
                 @endforeach()
                </tbody>
            </table>
            @else
            <p class="panel-content-result">Pas de résultat pour cette section</p>
            @endif
     </div>
    </div>

    <div class="footer">
  <div class="footer-left">
   <p>Association "Les Amis des Oiseaux" (AAO/BirdLife Tunisie)</p>
   <p>Immeuble ERIS Bureau N°4 au 2ème étage 14,</p>
   <p>Rue Ibn El Heni 2080 Ariana-Tunisie</p>
   <p>(+216) 53 937 127 / aao.org@gmail.com</p>
  </div>
  <div class="footer-right">
   <p>Observatoire citoyen des infractions à l’encontre<br> des oiseaux sauvages en Tunisie</p>
  </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question right, you want to download PDF file depending on your blade view? If that's true, you can make your blade as something like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <style>
        /*your css style*/
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    @foreach($users as $user)
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Firstname</th>
                <th>Lastname</th>
                <th>Email</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>{{$user->name}}</td>
                <td>{{$user->last_name}}</td>
                <td>{{$user->email}}</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    @endforeach
</body>
</html>
```

Then in your controller, to download your PDF file, you can do something like this:

```
if ($users) {
     $pdf = PDF::loadView('your_view', $users);
     $fileName = 'your_file_name.pdf'
     return $pdf->download($fileName);
} else {
     return redirect()->back();
}
```

Comment: i already can download PDF the problem is with the css of the downloaded PDF.I added the code in my question

Comment: Can you add your view file as well. Do you have any css in your view?